# Insert a liferay portlet into PrimeFaces dialog

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, liferay, liferay-6

I'm using liferay 6.1, jsf 2 and primeface 4.0. I've two different project running on a liferay tomcat. I want to insert a portlet of "Project 1" into primefaces dialog of "project 2".

I tried by using ui:insert, but it takes the source path of current project. How to proceed in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

with ui:insert, you can insert html code, not a whole portlet! 
So you should either:

1. Create a common xhtml page that could be visible from both portlets. This would require that you have both portlets in the same plugin project
2. In the dialog, instead of inserting code, you can include a link to another page of your portal, where a "project2" portlet is placed

Comment: There is also a sharing option for the portlet, which offers scripting mechanism to include your portlet in any html. Try it!

Comment: @Parkash Kumar this is interesting. Can you please share some resources about this, or some keywords to search about this feature ?

Comment: https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/administration/-/ai/shari-3

Answer (score 0):

I'm managed to fixed that issue.

1. Liferay provides a generate URL functionality of each portlet. So I created a URL for target portlet.
2. then pass that url to liferay pop up.

Here is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var url;
function createRenderURL() {

AUI().ready('liferay-portlet-url', function(A) {

var renderURL = Liferay.PortletURL.createRenderURL();

renderURL.setName("Banner");
renderURL .setPortletMode("view");
renderURL .setWindowState("pop_up");
renderURL.setPortletId("addUser_WAR_UserManagementportlet");
url = renderURL.toString();
showPopup(url);
});
}
function showPopup(url){

console.log("En el showPopup ");
AUI().ready('aui-dialog', 'aui-io', function(A) {
    alert(url);
    window.myDialog  = new A.Dialog({
        title: 'Banner',
        width: 640,
        centered: true
    }).plug(A.Plugin.IO, {
            uri: url
    }).render();
});
```

}

Hope it will help to another. Thanks.